# HTML5/SVG: preserveAspectRatio "none" not working in Firefox

Tags: html, svg

I'd like to use SVG images as background images html div elements. The SVG should get stretched accordingly to the div it is embedded into. This works nice in Google Chrome, but in Firefox, the SVG sticks to its width/height ratio when resizing and doesn't get stretched. I'm using `preserverAspectRatio = "none"`.

The SVG looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 180 95">
<g
 id="layer1">
<path
   d="m 1.0714286,31.469326 140.0000014,0 0,-30.0000009 30,40.0000009 -30,40 0,-30 -140.0000014,0 z"
   id="path3015"
   style="fill:#4f81bd; fill-opacity:1; stroke:#385d8a; stroke-width:3; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter; stroke-opacity:1" />
</g>
</svg>
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div style="
      width: 250px; 
      height: 200px; 
      background-image:url(file.svg); 
      background-repeat:no-repeat;">
          test
 </div>
```

In Chrome, I can change the width/height of the div element and the SVG image gets stretched without taking care of the original width/height ratio. This behaviour is intended. In Firefox, it just gets resized and keeps its original ratio. Do you know how I could change this? Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Try adding `background-size: 100% 100%;` to your 'style' `div` (it works for me).

Comment: Thank you so much. It took me a long time to find this. It also fixed a weird sizing bug on IE9 that I had.

Comment: I was using background-size : contain; but background-size: 100% 100%; fixed it for FF, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much! This saves the day and now my sites works on firefox as well as the others. Thanks.